# Changing link target to _blank has no effect

Tags: 2013, javascript

On my masterpage I have added the following script:

```
function replaceLink() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(i in elems) {
        var elem = elems[i];

        if(elem.hostname && elem.hostname !== location.hostname) {
            elem.target = "_blank";
        }
    }
}
```

This code runs, and after checking with the inspect elements tool I see that all external links now have `target="_blank"` set as their attribute. If I click on such a link however it opens in the same window, not in a new window / tab.

Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Try putting a link on the page manually with target set to "_blank", disable the javascript, and see if that link behaves as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Adding a link manualy with target blank opens it in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following function, you'll see that I replaced your for..in loop with a for. You should, generally speaking, not use a for..in loop to iterate an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

```
function replaceLink() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for(var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; ++i) {
        var elem = elems[i];

        if(elem.hostname && elem.hostname !== location.hostname) {
            elem.target = "_blank";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Ill consider that also in the future, but this wasnt the cause of the problem in this case.

Comment: What was the cause of the error?

Comment: I dont know yet, but as the problem persists even with this corrected version i think it was not the (only) problem that caused the links to open in the same window/tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the attribute target to _black using setAttribute.

function replaceLink() {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

```
for(i in elems) {
    var elem = elems[i];

    if(elem.hostname && elem.hostname !== location.hostname) {
        elem.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly the links still open in the same window even though i see the target="_blank" in the links attributes when i select "inspect element"